# Methods for evaluating partial autocorrelation for identification of ARIMA models

Tags: autocorrelation, arima

I am trying to programmatically identify an ARIMA model for a series of data and forecast values.

Currently the problem i am facing is to find a way to evaluate partial autocorrelation. I have been looking for methods to calculate PACF for quite a long time now but in vain.

Please provide some online resources which can help me in this matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Durbin-Levinson algorithm. It will be explained in any good time series book such as [Brockwell and Davis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387953515). Here are some online explanations:

- http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~berg/sta4853/files/sta4853-4.pdf
- http://amath.colorado.edu/courses/4540/2008Spr/HandOuts/DurbinLevinson.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You may also be interested in the 'auto.arima' function in the [forecast package](http://robjhyndman.com/software/forecast/) for [r](http://www.r-project.org/) as an example of a way to programmatically identify ARIMA models.  It probably doesn't find the model in the exact same way you would, but some of the code/ideas might be useful to you.